# Open DotNetNuke Link Popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

How can I open module content in a popup instead of a new page?

Currently, I am using a link inside a GridView like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdStudentAttendanceList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="false">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href='<%# DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL("AddOrUpdateStudent","StudentID=" + Eval("StudentID").ToString(),"mid=" + ModuleId) %>' class="">
                    <%# Eval("Surname").ToString()%>
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Describe more about the module content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for my question and it was very simple.

Just pass `NavigateURL` to `dnnModal.show` like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surname" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="javascript:dnnModal.show('<%#DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL("AddOrUpdateStudent","StudentID=" + Eval("StudentID").ToString(),"mid=" + ModuleId) + "?popUp=true" %>',false,550,950,true)" class="">
            <%# Eval("Surname").ToString()%>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

***Note:** The addition of the `?popUp=true` URL query parameter.*

Answer (score 2):

Check out my blog post about modal popups in DNN

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3427/Using-dnnModal-show-in-your-modules-and-content.aspx